# How to push my changes to Bit bucket feature branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, push

I created a separate branch from master on Bit bucket through their interface, called it "doctor-edits", cloned that onto my machine and now that I've made my changes I'm trying to push them back there, however, if I do a 'git remote -v' it gives me:

"origin  https://doctorprofessor@bitbucket.org/ourteam_team/pmx.git (fetch)"

"origin  https://doctorprofessor@bitbucket.org/ourteam_team/pmx.git (push)"

That makes me think if I do a "git push origin" that will just push it to the master whereas I'm trying to push to my feature branch.
Some light on this would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how the output of `git remote` leads you to thinking that. Have you tried to use `git push`?

Comment: ok so it is embarrassing, I cloned that feature branch repo and now I'm trying to push back to it. I I just do git push will it go to master or feature? git branch gives me *master ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `git branch` to check if you work in the right branch. if it's true then you can push your changes using  `git push` to the branch you are working on.